# How to define maven test-jar dependency in sbt

Tags: scala, sbt

I have the following maven dependency

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
      <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
      <version>0.90.4</version>
      <type>test-jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

I know how to specify groupId,artifactId, version and scope

```
 "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.90.4" % "test"
```

but how do I specify the type (test-jar) so that I'd get hbase-0.90.4-tests.jar  from the repo?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

`"org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "0.90.4" % "test" classifier "tests"`

Comment: Its confusing that the "type" in maven translates to classifier in sbt. Because, maven has "classifier" in addition to "type". Wonder, what the classifier in maven translate to in sbt ?

Comment: This is a dark corner of sbt. If you add a dependency that itself has dependencies in it's pom.xml that have a <type> of test-jar then sbt (or possibly ivy) won't download those dependencies.

Comment: I'm already opting to specify, and deploy, test-jar artifacts/dependencies explicitly as jar with tests classifier.