# How to include spark tests as Maven dependency

Tags: maven, apache-spark

I have inherited old code that depends on

```
org.apache.spark.LocalSparkContext
```

which is in the spark core tests. But the spark core jar (correctly) does not include test-only classes. I was unable to determine if/where spark test classes have their own maven artifacts.  What is the correct approach here?

Comment: OK I see this "Josh Rosen added a comment - 16/Sep/15 18:57
We're using test-jar dependencies instead, so this is "Won't Fix"."  So apparently we need to figure out how to use test-jar dependencies.. or maybe as you say it requires manual building of the test-jar in which case I would just copy and paste the class. btw If you want some points you can make this an answer and I will award.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add a dependency to the `test-jar` of Spark by adding `<type>test-jar</type>`. For example, for Spark 1.5.1 based on Scala 2.11:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.1</version>
  <type>test-jar</type>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

This dependency provides all the test classes of Spark, including `LocalSparkContext`.

Answer (score 1):

I came here hoping to find some inspiration for doing the same in SBT. As a reference for other SBT users: Applying the [pattern of using test-jars in SBT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8076568/1804173) for Spark 2.0 results in:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.0.0" classifier "tests"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.0.0" classifier "tests"
```

Comment: This is certainly useful for `sbt` users

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add test jars , might go ahead adding in SBT as mentioned below:

```
version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.11"
val sparkVersion = "2.3.1"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Provided,
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "tests",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-catalyst" % sparkVersion % Test classifier "test-sources",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.4" % "test")
```

The same if you want to add it over the MAVEN dependencies, you can do it by as mentioned below :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.parent.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.parent.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <classifier>tests</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.parent.version}</artifactId>
        <version>${spark.version}</version>
        <classifier>test-sources</classifier>
        <type>test-jar</type>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

<dependencies>
```